# Ranking data and then average out all the rankings, and rank those

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

Here's basically what I want to do. Say you're building a website that ranks people getting high scores in a video game. You have one user, and he score 100, 150, and 200 on Level 1, 2, and 3 respectively. You then have another user who gets scores of 200, 100, and 100. If you are looking at User 1, you would get a table like this:

```
         | Score | Rank |
Level 1: |  100  |  2   |
Level 2: |  150  |  1   |
Level 3: |  200  |  1   |
```

I've already found out how to store the scores in a MySQL table and then ranking the data. Here's where it gets a little tricky. Say you want to average out all the rankings for a user. For User 1, you would get 1.333. For User 2, you would get 1.666. So if you ranked that data, you would get a table like this:

```
        | Average Rank | Rank |
User 1: |  1.333       |  1   |
User 2: |  1.666       |  2   |
```

Basically, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would probably be to use aggregate functions in your MySQL query when you pull the data.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 "SELECT level, AVG(Rank) FROM (YOUR TABLE NAME HERE) GROUP BY level"
```

Will give you an average of the rank column for one of your tables. I'm assuming each table represents a player. if that's the case, you'd have to run this query on each of the user tables. Also note, I'm assuming that level 1 - level 3 is your unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming your table is similar to

```
LevelID (int)
UserID (int)
Score (int)
```

You'd probably do something like

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT *, AVG(Score) as AverageScore, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as Rank FROM scores
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY `AverageScore` DESC
```

The reason I used average score and rank instead of average rank, is who uses average rank? That's strange, and harder to calculate. If you show your SQL for fetching Rank, then it'll be easier. If you're actually storing the rank in the table (which is not good practice), then you can just order by UserID and AVG(Rank)